# Google Play services crashes(gapps)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

In my device i got following error

`unfortunately the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped`

After this my app is also crashing. I put Acra for cash logs. But its not added in Acra. I am using play store library for GCM and Map.

Is this a device specific issue?

Comment: Check the Play service version you have used in your application, if your device play service version is lower then you have used in your application then update play service in your device and check it

Comment: you have to copy the logcat of the device

Comment: Please follows [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) steps to set up your google play services, moreover, you can provide the logcat of your app crashes.

Comment: logs are not getting . I am using com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0 in gradle